# Memory issues with python multiprocessing and hundreds of threads active

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I'm using the package Multiprocessing.dummy, which I read is just the threading package, for reading in some files. I'm also using just Multiprocessing for calculations. I'm running my code in Spyder, and after running it a few times for different files or calculations, I start to get errors with the parallel code. Usually the errors are related to memory, like `OS Error: [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory` which occurs in the multiprocessing/threading code.

I noticed that the number of threads keeps increasing, and I'm wondering if this is part of the problem. For example, earlier I saw `multiprocessing.threading.active_count() = 277`. These are both DummyProcess and Thread threads. Eventually, running the code seems to kill/reset Spyder. My parallel code looks like this:

```
# I/O example
io_pool = multiprocessing.dummy.Pool()
io_pool.map(func,files)

# Comp example
cpu_pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
cpu_pool.map(func, var)
```

Is there a way to kill the active threads? I can't seem to join or close them, not sure how exactly this works though.

Comment: Always use context managers for this kind of thing. Please include all your code as well as any necessary data. See: [mcve]. Also, are you on Microsoft Windows?

Comment: Never heard of context managers, I'll look into it